# Matching Portions of A String to Elements of an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, match

I have a string & an array, and am trying to iterate through the array to see of any of its elements match a portion of the string.

```
string = "HOPJYJKCONNECTICUTQZIDAHOKR"

states_array = ["TEXAS", "ALASKA", "IDAHO", "FLORIDA", "MONTANA", "OHIO", "NEWMEXICO", "CONNECTICUT", "COLORADO"]
```

How can I iterate overs the states_array so that I can find all matches in the string? I would  want to output all the matched states as an array & so the final result might look like:

```
#=> ["CONNECTICUT", "IDAHO"]
```

Comment: Should be `"TEXAS","ALASKA",` not `"TEXAS,""ALASKA,"`

Comment: There is a Syntax error in your comment... seriously?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I'm referring to `#=> ["CONNECTICUT", "IDAHO"]` in the question.

Comment: WPeter Alfvin There is a comma after the end of a string definition.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Oops nevermind I was referring to something else but it got fixed (The first comment by steenslag)

Comment: @Doorhandle And as I said, that was a reference to the _code_, not to the comments. It also wasn't a syntax error per se. The code as originally shown would have produced an array with a single string in it resulting from the concatenation of all the string literals between the brackets.

Answer (score 5):

```
string = "HOPJYJKCONNECTICUTQZIDAHOKR"
states = ["TEXAS", "ALASKA", "IDAHO", "FLORIDA", "MONTANA", "OHIO", "NEWMEXICO", "CONNECTICUT", "COLORADO"]

states.select { |s| string[s] }
# => ["IDAHO", "CONNECTICUT"]
```

Comment: excellent. thank you. new to this & was not sure if I had to iterate over each element of the array before matching it to the string. much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Nice solution by Matt but can also be done

```
states.select { |s| string.match(s)}
```

Comment: Or `states.select { |s| string.include? s }` but it's basically the same  thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified the regex tag on this question, you could do with with a regex as follows:

```
string.scan(Regexp.new(states.join('|')))
# => ["CONNECTICUT", "IDAHO"]
```

using the variables in Matt's answer. Not recommending this, however. :-)

Comment: Good points: (1) The OP did specify regex. (2) This gives the answer in the same order as the OP. +1

Comment: Thanks, but not sure what you mean by "same order as the OP". In fact, reviewing the question, the OP ask about "iterating over the states", which this doesn't do. ;-)

Comment: Meaning that the answer `["CONNECTICUT", "IDAHO"]` is ordered the same as in the OP, which is the same as in `string`.

Answer (score 0):

This is like @Peter_Alvin's answer,using the built in method `union`.

```
states_array = ["TEXAS", "ALASKA", "IDAHO", "FLORIDA", "MONTANA", "OHIO", "NEWMEXICO", "CONNECTICUT", "COLORADO"]
str = "HOPJYJKCONNECTICUTQZIDAHOKR"
p str.scan(Regexp.union(states_array)) # ["CONNECTICUT", "IDAHO"]
```